# Using max for each sub group does not seem to work.

Tags: oracle-11g, subquery

I have a table that looks like this in Oracle 11g:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| ACCT_NBR | MAIL_TY | ORGA      | PERS       | RUN_DATE   |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 123      | ALT     | 2         |            | 21-JAN-13  |
| 123      | ALT     | 2         |            | 22-FEB-13  |
| 123      | ALT     |           | 3          | 23-FEB-13  |
| 124      | PRI     | 4         |            | 24-JAN-13  |
| 124      | PRI     | 4         |            | 25-FEB-13  |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to get the latest RUN_DATE based on Orga and Pers columns. So that the table looks like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| ACCT_NBR | MAIL_TY | ORGA      | PERS       | RUN_DATE   |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 123      | ALT     | 2         |            | 22-FEB-13  |
| 123      | ALT     |           | 3          | 23-FEB-13  |
| 124      | PRI     | 4         |            | 25-FEB-13  |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried using this query but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Select *  
from wh_acct   
where a.rundate = (select max(a2.rundate)  
from wh_acct a2)  
WHERE a2.ORGA = a.ORGA)
UNION
Select *  
from wh_acct   
where a.rundate = (select max(a2.rundate)  
from wh_acct a2)  
WHERE a2.PERS = a.PERS)
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Why won't `select acct_nbr, mail_ty, orga, pers, max(run_date) from wh_acct group by acct_nbr, mail_ty, orga, pers` work?

Answer (score 4):

You have two right parenthesis more than left ones and `a` missing alias:

```
Select *  
from wh_acct a                                 -- alias added
where a.rundate = 
      (select max(a2.rundate)  
       from wh_acct a2                         -- parenthesis removed
       WHERE a2.ORGA = a.ORGA)
UNION
Select *  
from wh_acct a                                 -- alias added 
where a.rundate = 
      (select max(a2.rundate)  
       from wh_acct a2                         -- parenthesis removed
       WHERE a2.PERS = a.PERS) ;
```

You could also write the query with `OR` instead of `UNION`:

```
Select *  
From wh_acct a
Where a.rundate = 
      (Select max(a2.rundate)  
       From wh_acct a2   
       Where a2.ORGA = a.ORGA)
   Or a.rundate = 
      (Select max(a2.rundate)  
       From wh_acct a2   
       Where a2.PERS = a.PERS) ;
```

Or using window functions:

```
WITH cte AS
    ( SELECT ACCT_NBR, MAIL_TY, ORGA, PERS, RUN_DATE, 
             MAX(rundate) OVER (PARTITION BY ORGA) AS max_rundate_orga,
             MAX(rundate) OVER (PARTITION BY PERS) AS max_rundate_pers 
      FROM wh_acct
    ) 
SELECT ACCT_NBR, MAIL_TY, ORGA, PERS, RUN_DATE
FROM cte
WHERE rundate = max_rundate_orga
   OR rundate = max_rundate_pers ;
```

---

If, as your sample shows, all rows have `NULL` in `orga` where there is a value in `pers` and vice versa, you can change the `UNION` to `UNION ALL` to improve efficiency as there would be no need to check the subresults for duplicates (which is what `UNION` does). The window-cte version could also be rewritten as a union (`ALL`) of 2 subqueries.

Indexes on `(orga, run_date)` and `(pers, run_date)` would help, too.

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed response. Very helpful. I dont know why but when I run this, it gives me results for only those rows that don't have null in ORGA where there is a value in pers. so for acctnbr 123, it will just give me the value for pers. Weird thing is, it runs perfectly in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8a83a/1

Comment: In the Fiddle you have `rundate` as varchar. Why not `date`? Is this a typo in setting up the fiddle?

Comment: yes that is a typo. thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score -3):

You can use the anlytics function for this:
Function(arg1,..., argn) OVER ( [PARTITION BY <...>] [ORDER BY <....>] [])

Examples:

http://www.orafaq.com/node/55

Comment: Could you be more specific?  At least you should show how this relates to the question.

Comment: Add some example code so the OP (and the rest of us dummies) can understand what you mean.